# Kendo UI MVC Grid always trying to save 2 records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have configured this grid to autoSync, so that you can edit it and every time you change a field, it will submit the Update action. For this to work, you have to set the Batch(true) property, which supports editing multiple rows, but that is not how I am using it as the autosync automatically fires the update event, you don't get an opportunity to edit multiple rows before calling update.

For some reason, it is always submitting a new record Update. For example, when I click the Add New toolbar button `toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Time Task");`), you can see in the Chrome dev tools network tab that 2 records are being submitted to my controller...a model[0] and model[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8T5M.png) in a single update call.

But if I perform an InCell edit, and leave focus of the cell to trigger the update call...2 separate update calls are being made...the first one is an Add New (I can tell because the Id = 0 and all the defaults are as per my grid configuration).

Anyone know why this Add New type call is being triggered?

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

@Html.Partial("_IndexEditViewHeader")

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OTIS.AppServ.Shared.ViewModels.TimeTaskViewModel>()
    .Name("TimeTasksGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(l => l.Id).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(l => l.CompanyId).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(l => l.CompanyName);
        columns.Bound(l => l.TaskDescription);
        columns.Bound(l => l.TaskTypeId)
            .EditorTemplateName("TimeTaskTypesDDL")
            .ClientTemplate("#= TaskTypeDescription #");
        columns.Bound(l => l.UserSelectable)
            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value='#= UserSelectable #' " +
                                "class='chkbx' onclick='setCheckBoxModelValue(this,&quot;TimeTasksGrid&quot;,&quot;UserSelectable&quot;)'" +
                                "# if (UserSelectable) { #" +
                                    "checked='checked'" +
                                "# } #" +
                            " />"
                        );
        columns.Bound(l => l.HoursMultiplier);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
    })
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    // Add "Create" command
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Time Task");
        //toolbar.Save();
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax() // Specify that the data source is of ajax type
        .ServerOperation(false) // paging, sorting, filtering and grouping will be applied client-side
        .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(c => c.Id);
                model.Field(c => c.CompanyId).DefaultValue(ViewBag.CompanyId);
                model.Field(c => c.TaskDescription).DefaultValue("Task Description");
                model.Field(c => c.TaskTypeId).DefaultValue(20);
                model.Field(c => c.TaskTypeDescription).DefaultValue("Billable");
                model.Field(c => c.HoursMultiplier).DefaultValue(1);
            }
        )
        .Sort(sort =>
        {
            sort.Add(c => c.CompanyName);
            sort.Add(c => c.TaskDescription);
        })
        // Specify a handler for the error event
        .Events(events => events.Error("KendoGridErrors"))
        .Batch(true)
        // CRUD configuration -->
        .Create(create => create.Action("Grid_SaveOrUpdate", "ManageTimeTasks", new { area = "Shared" }))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "ManageTimeTasks", new { area = "Shared" })// Specify the action method and controller name
        )
        .Update(update => update.Action("Grid_SaveOrUpdate", "ManageTimeTasks", new { area = "Shared" }))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Grid_Delete", "ManageTimeTasks", new { area = "Shared" }))
            // <-- CRUD configuration      
    )
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
)

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#TimeTasksGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.options.autoSync = true;
    });
</script>
```

Picture of double call to Update upon editing a single cell:
[image]

Comment: What are you doing in the Grid_SaveOrUpdate controller action?  On a create, you have to return the created item in the response with its non-zero ID set otherwise the Kendo Grid will still think it is new(id == 0) on the next post and submit it for create again.  Check out the implementation of Editing_Create at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing and look at what it is returning.

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen thanks for the idea. I am doing that. But this doesn't seem to be the issue. If I refresh my page, so there are no pending updates or any action at all, and then make an edit to any cell, the result is 2 distinct calls to my controller action. The first's data model is for a new record with ID = 0....this is the problem call. The second call is the correct update call with the data model of the truly edited record. See picture I added to original question.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a fun 6 hours figuring this out. It turns out that on our test database, someone turned off the Identity default specification on the Id primary key column. Then during testing, a test record with an Id = 0 was saved, so that was being into the grid every time, then when you'd save or update another row, that row with the Id = 0 was also in that batch trying to be saved.